# How do I setup Cassandra on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-20.04

Hi Im new on cassandra and I running ubuntu OS. How do I set up cassandra in ubuntu 20?. Why Im I getting so many errors? This is the last one I come across, I have tried everything
cassandra
.....
ERROR org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories - Doesn't have write permissions for /var/lib/cassandra/data directory

before that one I got this one
cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

Comment: It will be great if you describe what you did and which instruction you have followed and how diverged from instructions.

Comment: k_rus I followed these instructions. Still I get the connection error when I run cqlsh

Comment: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-cassandra-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the default `cassandra` user does not have permissions on the data directory.

Ordinarily for package installations, it will automatically create the directories for you with the correct permissions but if you manually created directories before running the installation, there's a possibility that you created them as `root` so Cassandra can't access them.

If so, you will need to reset the permissions to the `cassandra` user for all the directories and subdirectories in `/var/lib/cassandra`.

For details, see the [Installation instructions](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html) I wrote in the official Apache Cassandra website. Cheers!

Comment: Actually, I managed to run Cassandra. The problem comes out when I try to install DataStax, it returns to the same error and it doesn't even create the dse.jaml file